# How to use hive hook in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I use hive(2.1.1) hook like following:

```
set hive.exec.post.hooks=com.test.HiveTestHook;create table tmp.hive_hook_test(x int);
```

And I want to run this sql in spark sql(2.4.0) yet, but i found hook is not  invoked. 
I run spark sql like:

```
spark-sql -e 'set spark.hadoop.hive.exec.post.hooks=com.test.HiveTestHook;create table tmp.hive_hook_test(x int);'
```

So I want to know how to use hive hook in spark sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark dont support hive hooks, details refer to: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18879